# How to get my likes in python?

Tags: python, soundcloud

Ok so I'm trying to get my likes in python in the same format as I use " get('e1/me/stream.json) ". My understanding is that I can only use v1 with get in python. Listening the requests I tried this url :

https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/track_likes/ids?app_version=c53f4bf&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea&cursor=1426363878000000&limit=5000&linked_partitioning=1&page_number=0&page_size=200

I get 401 Unauthorized everytime, but what's weird is that if I go to another url and then hit previous all the ids are displayed.

It used to be as simple as get(e1/me/likes.json) but now it doesn't work anymore.

Thank you so much and happy holidays to you guys!
Alex

Comment: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python

Comment: Using their documentation I can't get my likes in the format that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is

```
me/favorites?oauth_token=your_auth_token
```

Weird that it's perfectly fine to get your stream (`https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/stream.json?`) but need authentification for your public likes.